# How to get back full file after assignment with jq?

Tags: json, edit, jq

[jq▸play example](https://jqplay.org/s/Hta2KrMn-G)

This filter:

```
.versions[].columns[] | select(.type == "varchar" and .length < 255) | .length = 255
```

Updates my data how I'd like, but I want to get back the full file/input in the end, not just the columns that were modified. How can I do that?

I don't want to delete the columns that don't match the `select` (just leave them unchanged)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply update your `.columns` property:

```
.versions[].columns
 |= map(if (.type == "varchar" and .length < 255) then .length = 255 else . end)
```

https://jqplay.org/s/xjMiqANQ3p

Comment: I think that's deleting columns that don't match the `select` -- I want to leave those unmodified

Comment: @mpen, post the expected result

Comment: Here: https://gist.github.com/mnpenner/f0dcd9ccfaa45ed1c0805b7eca16c1e7 Just the varchar columns with length less than 255 are upped to 255. Everything else stays the same.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you :-)